# ListView android and null pointer exception

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to show a simple `ListView` ,but I have some problems .It seems that I had a `NullPointerException` .
Here's the **XML** :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    />
```

and my main class :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private List<String> exemple;
private ListView liste=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   exemple=new ArrayList<String>();

    exemple.add("Item 1");
    exemple.add("Item 2");
    exemple.add("Item 3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exemple);
    liste.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

I got this error :

```
07-07 11:59:27.024    2758-2758/tunisia_sat.com.essai E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: tunisia_sat.com.essai, PID: 2758
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{tunisia_sat.com.essai/tunisia_sat.com.essai.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: move your `private ListView liste=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);` in `onCreate()` after `setContentView()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `liste` initialization after `setContentView`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
liste = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

**Why NullPointerException?**
You are calling `ssetAdapter` on null reference `liste` in the following line:

```
liste.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`liste` is null because it is being initialized before view is up(binding activity with view). So, findViewById returns Null.

Answer (score 2):

Do not initialize `ListView` in declaration. Just do this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private List<String> exemple;
private ListView liste;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    liste = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    exemple=new ArrayList<String>();
    exemple.add("Item 1");
    exemple.add("Item 2");
    exemple.add("Item 3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exemple);
    liste.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Cast your listview after setting contentView int your onCreate method:

so you should do this:

outside your method, declare your ListView.

```
ListView listView;
```

So then cast in onCreate method:

```
listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

Regards.

Comment: why to repeat answer ?

Comment: well, maybe because when i write mi answer i didnt see the first one... perhaps was not intencionally.

Answer (score 0):

```
Write the following statement 

ListView liste=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

in Oncreate() method after 

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Example:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ListView liste=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView); 

   exemple=new ArrayList<String>(); 
    exemple.add("Item 1");
    exemple.add("Item 2");
    exemple.add("Item 3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exemple);
    liste.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: why to repeat answer ?